# Fish Shell: How to interpret git response?

Tags: git, shell, fish

For my workspace environment I'm currently creating a script to easily switch between my development and release branches. Unfortunately the repo's do not always have similar branch name, therefor I check if the branch exists and if the branch has already been merged to master. If the branch has not been merged to master, I know I have the latest release branch.

```
        set repo_has_changes (git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no)

        if test -n $repo_has_changes
            echo 'Repo has changes...'
        else
            git checkout master

            for b in $releaseVersions
                set branch_on_origin (git branch -r --list origin/$b)
                set branch_not_merged_to_master (git branch -r --list --no-merged master origin/$b)

                if test -n $branch_on_origin
                    if test -z $branch_not_merged_to_master
                        git checkout $b
                        git pull
                        break
                    end
                end
            end
        end
```

In my ignorance I thought I store the result of my git command, and store it in a variable. I interpreted it as string. According to the fish documentation I can test if a string is non-zero.

> -n STRING returns true if the length of STRING is non-zero.

This script will always echo 'Repo has changes...' while I'm 100% sure it doesn't have changes.
If I echo $repo_has_changes I see an empty line. Also if I check the length of the string (just in case string returns spaces? xD ) it also returns an empty line. So my assumption that $repo_has_changes is a string might be wrong. Also I'm not certain that I'm able to store the git result in this fashion. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a good source for this.

Comment: I don't use fish and can't speak to its particular rules, but in other shells, `if test -n $foo` *must* be spelled `if test -n "$foo"` if `$foo` can ever be empty, otherwise you run `test -n` rather than `test -n <the-empty-string>`. Separate from that, see `git_sh_setup` (distributed with Git, but written for sh/bash) as it has utility functions for testing index-and-work-tree clean-ness. Your test to see if `origin/$b` exists can be spelled `git rev-parse -q --verify refs/remotes/origin/$b`, which exits 0 (and prints hash ID) if the remote-tracking name exists, or exits 1 if not.

Comment: Thank you sir for clearing this up for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, fish's `test` is one of the few parts that follow POSIX to the letter, and that specifies that `test` with any one argument has to return true, to facilitate uses like `test "thestring"`. Unfortunately this also means that `test -n` has to return true.

Which indeed means you need to quote any variable you pass to `test`:

```
test -n "$branch_on_origin"
```

and

```
test -z "$branch_not_merged_to_master"
```

Comment: Does fish still store the *lines* of a command substitution in the variable as array elements? Perhaps `count` would be a better test.

Comment: I ended up changing it into:
```
test -n "$branch_not_merged_to_master"
```
the variable will be filled if the branch is not merged ofcourse :)

Thanks for the quick response! :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous response pretty much answers your question I would assume. However, I recently developed my own custom prompt for fish that includes a right hand prompt. I put my git information in the right hand side. I won't attach both files, but I will provide the contents of the right side prompt function file. It doesn't display exactly what you requested, but within the function there examples that cover the same information and more. If nothing else I'm hoping it will be a good example of handling git information in the fish prompt.

My right side prompt function file (~/.config/fish/functions/fish_right_prompt.fish):

```
function fish_right_prompt -d "Write out the right prompt"
    set -l last_status $status # Special variable for storing last `$status` returned by terminal.
    set -l is_git_repository (git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree ^/dev/null) # Special variable indicating git.
    # ==============
    # Status Segment
    # ==============
    # This segment is not visible in the prompt by default. It checks the `$last_status` variable to see if the
    # terminal's last executed command or function returned an error status. If it did then the status segment is
    # generated based on the returned status code, formatted and colored accordingly, and printed to prompt.
    # --------------
    if not test $last_status -eq 0 # Test if `$last_status` is not equal to `0`.
        set_color -o red # Color the prompt bold red.
        # Eventually it would be cool to include conditional programming here to generate unique output for any
        # error cases to print to the prompt. For now, I'm just going to have this segment print a generic
        # formatted string to the prompt in the event of any errors.
        printf "%b" "\U203C Error Code $last_status \U203C"
        set_color normal
    end
    # ===========
    # Git Segment
    # ===========
    # An optional segment that is generated and printed to the prompt if the PWD is a git repository. If the
    # segment is generated it displays a variety of indicators and information depending on the current state of
    # repo.
    # -----------
    if test -n "$is_git_repository" # Test if the PWD is an active git repository.
        set_color A3A3A3 # Color the prompt grey. (Uses a hex color.)
        echo -n "[git:" # Echo the git repo indicator.
        set -l branch (git symbolic-ref --short HEAD ^/dev/null; or git show-ref --head -s --abbrev | head -n1 ^/dev/null)
        git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules ^/dev/null; or set -l has_unstaged_files
        git diff-index --quiet --ignore-submodules --cached HEAD ^/dev/null; or set -l has_staged_files
        if set -q has_unstaged_files # Check if the repo is unstaged.
            set_color red # Color the prompt red.
        else if set -q has_staged_files # Check if the repo is staged.
            set_color yellow # Color the prompt yellow.
        else # If the repo is clean then proceed.
            set_color green # Color the prompt green.
        end
        echo -n "$branch]" # Echo the git branch into the prompt.
        git rev-parse --abbrev-ref '@{upstream}' >/dev/null ^&1; and set -l has_upstream # Set `$has_upstream`.
        if set -q has_upstream # Check if the repository has any upstream.
            set -l commit_counts (git rev-list --left-right --count 'HEAD...@{upstream}' ^/dev/null) # Commit counts.
            set -l commits_to_push (echo $commit_counts | cut -f 1 ^/dev/null) # Commits to push.
            set -l commits_to_pull (echo $commit_counts | cut -f 2 ^/dev/null) # Commits to pull.
            if test $commits_to_push != 0 # Check if there any commits to push.
                if test $commits_to_pull -ne 0 # Check if there are any commits to pull.
                    set_color red # Color the prompt red.
                else if test $commits_to_push -gt 3 # Check if there are more than 3 commits to push.
                    set_color yellow # Color the prompt yellow.
                else # If there are no commits to pull, and no more than 3 commits to push, then proceed.
                    set_color green # Color the prompt green.
                end
                echo -n " ⇡ " # Echo the upstream push symbol.
            end
            if test $commits_to_pull != 0 # Check if there are any commits to pull.
                if test $commits_to_push -ne 0 # Check if there are any commits to push
                    set_color red # Color the prompt red.
                else if test $commits_to_pull -gt 3 # Check if there are more than 3 commits to pull.
                    set_color yellow # Color the prompt yellow.
                else # If no commits to push, and no more than 3 commits to pull, then proceed. 
                    set_color green # Color the prompt green.
                end
                echo -n " ⇣ " # Echo the upstream pull symbol.
            end
            set_color normal # Reset color and text decoration.
        end
        if test (git stash list | wc -l) -gt 0 # Check if there are any stashed changes.
            set_color A3A3A3 # Color the prompt grey. (Uses a hex color.)
            echo -n " ☰ " # Echo the stacked changes symbol.
        end
        set_color normal # Reset color and text decoration.
    end
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # That's all there is to right side secondary prompt. All other prompt segments can be found in the fish
    # function file for the primary prompt: `fish_prompt.fish`.
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
end
```